# Pi 1 Model B and Minecraft Pi

Tags: raspbian, minecraft

After having not used the Pi in a few months I installed Jessie and updated everything.  Once fully booted up and everything I attempted to run Minecraft to poor results.  **CPU was 100%, everything at a standstill.**  I once attempted to run Minecraft about a year or so ago and things seemed OK.

I'm wondering:  Is Jessie the problem or is it the older Pi?  I was hoping my son could use the Pi and learn some programming with Minecraft.  Anyone have any ideas?  Will a new Pi 3 run it better?  I can't seem to find anything anywhere of similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pi 3 definitely runs it better. The processor in the Pi 3 is substantially more powerful than the Pi 1, and the additional RAM helps too.

Also I ran it on a Pi 1 (about a year ago) without experiencing the slowdown you describe. (Well, ok... it wasn't blazing fast, but it was still playable on the Pi 1 too.)

Also also, there are some great Minecraft Pi programming tutorials out there that deal with scripting entire houses, etc.  Lots of fun.

Comment: I figure of course that a Pi 3 would run it better.  Just curious if my performance issues are hardware or software related or just normal.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you mean by "poor results" it's hard to answer that question. My overall experience was acceptable on the Pi 1, and of course, better on Pi 3.

Comment: I'll probably just get a new Pi anyway, as it sounds like the 3 is more than capable.